# Cannot get past start screen in Spore

Tags: spore

I just installed the game Spore. When I first dowloaded it off of Steam and updated it I thought it would work fine; I did my "homework" by searching in forums and such about reviews of the game so I went ahead and bought Spore & Spore galactic adventures.

It started off fine but then all that was on the screen was a frozen galaxy. After waiting for about thirty seconds I tried clicking all over the screen and found out that you can drag the camera view around to get different perspectives, so I closed the page and tried to open it again and I also tried restarting my computer. That did not help so I went on Google and searched "Spore starting screen glitches", ect., all to no avail.

I run it on Windows Vista and I have a 2.50 GHz processer. How can I make it work?

Comment: Oi, wracking brains on this as my spore playing was a Long time ago. But I believe the galaxy screen you are on are your saved races (games).. There should be like a glowing planet or something of that ilk that you can select as you peer around that screen.. Not an answer because I can not install the game at work to test out my recollection :D

Comment: James you are correct. The galaxy is the saved game selection screen. Several planets in the galaxy should be highlighted, and when you click one, it should prompt you to start a new game there or load an existing game.

Answer (score 1):

If you can move around the screen then you should be able to select one of the planets (not sure which).

Answer (score 1):

If you can change perspective or make the galaxy move, then Spore is running. Click on a tiny blue circle to start a game. The galaxy map is a graphic "select new or saved game" menu. Spore creates six yellow circles that act as empty "new game" save slots. Clicking on one of these will start the actual game.

Once a game is created, you will find it from the main galaxy menu map in the future, surrounded by a blue dashed circle, with extra arrows pointing at it if it's the last save you've played.

As you fill up the existing new game slots with actual games, Spore will create new empty slots for you to create new games in.

Spore can take a very long time to start. On good machines, I've had it take several minutes. Once a game makes it to the galaxy main menu screen, I've seen moderately powerful machines need another minute or two before the screen can respond to user input. It requires patience when you first start Spore if you haven't ran Spore in a significant time.